# Web API method not fetching data after adding OData functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API with Angular 6 as frontend.

I have added OData functionality to the `Startup.cs` file in the Web API project. I also use Swagger to document the API.

This is the code in the `Startup.cs` file for `ConfigureServices`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOData();
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddMvc(opt =>
    {
        opt.UseGeneralRoutePrefix("BookManagement");
        opt.SslPort = SettingsLoader<AppSettings>.Settings.SslPort;
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1); ;

    services.AddMvcCore(options =>
    {
        foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<OutputFormatter>().Where(x => x.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
        {
            outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
        }

        foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<InputFormatter>().Where(x => x.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
        {
            inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
        }
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddRequestScopingMiddleware(() => _scopeProvider.Value = new Scope());
    services.AddCustomControllerActivation(Resolve);
    services.AddCustomViewComponentActivation(Resolve);


    // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc($"v{AppVersion.cVersion}", new Info { Title = "Books Microservice", Version = $"v{AppVersion.cVersion}" });
        c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Synergy.AssetsModule.WebApi.xml"));
    });
}
```

`Configure` method is as below

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Kernel = RegisterApplicationComponents(app);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    if (SettingsLoader<AppSettings>.Settings.AutoUpdateDatabase)
    {
        IDatabaseLogic databaseLogic = new DatabaseLogic(Kernel.Get<IDatabasePersistence>());
        databaseLogic.UpgradeDatabase();
    }
    InitiateMessageReprocess();

    #if !NO_AUTH
        ISingleSignOnLogic singleSignOnLogic = Kernel.Get<ISingleSignOnLogic>();
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationFilter>(singleSignOnLogic);
    #endif

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/v{AppVersion.cVersion}/swagger.json", $"Books Microservice API v{AppVersion.cVersion}");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });

    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
    });

    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        routeBuilder.Expand().Select().Count().OrderBy().Filter();
    });

    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, SettingsLoader<AppSettings>.Settings.SslPort));

    LogProvider.Instance.LogInformation("Started application");
}
```

With this code, the Swagger API is returning 204 Undocumented.

Don't know where it is going wrong. The parameter content type previously I was using is `application/json-patch+json`. Please suggest why I am not getting the data from the Web API method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.  First, I would suggest creating a separate web service to host your OData endpoints.  Second, prior to .net 6, it's somewhat difficult to get OData and Swagger to work together.  Even in .net 6, there are a few things missing when it comes to swagger.

I have an open-source project that fills in the gaps.  Here's a sample project that illustrates how to use it.

https://github.com/ikemtz/NRSRx/tree/master/samples/IkeMtz.Samples.OData